# Can SageMath environment libraries be converted to SymPy libraries for running code on different hardware devices that do not support SageMath?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, sage, polynomial-math, pydroid

I have a python script I am testing that uses the SageMath environment on my Linux desktop.  I am trying to convert several lines of code to SymPy so that I can run the program on my mobile devices PyDroid 3 app (SageMath is too resource intensive to install and run on my mobile phone).

The SageMath library modules and functions I am trying to convert are GF, and PolynomialRing.  SymPy seems to be the logical choice for use of its libraries to match the SageMath ones, or is there a Pip python version I can install from SageMath with these two particular modules without having to install the entire SageMath environment?

The script I am working with was authored by Kudelski Security, and is provided below.

The original code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sage

from sagemath import GF, PolynomialRing
import hashlib
import ecdsa
import random

def separator():
    print("-" * 150)


#####################
# global parameters #
#####################

# choose any curve
usedcurve = ecdsa.curves.SECP256k1
# usedcurve = ecdsa.curves.NIST521p
# usedcurve = ecdsa.curves.BRAINPOOLP160r1

print("Selected curve :")
print(usedcurve.name)
separator()

# the private key that will be guessed
g = usedcurve.generator
d = random.randint(1, usedcurve.order - 1)
print("TYPES: ", type(g), type(d))

pubkey = ecdsa.ecdsa.Public_key( g, g * d )
privkey = ecdsa.ecdsa.Private_key( pubkey, d )
print("Private key :")
print(d)
separator()

# N = the number of signatures to use, N >= 4
# the degree of the recurrence relation is N-3
# the number of unknown coefficients in the recurrence equation is N-2
# the degree of the final polynomial in d is 1 + Sum_(i=1)^(i=N-3)i

N = 7
assert N >= 4

############################################################
# nonces and signature generation with recurrence relation #
############################################################

# first, we randomly generate the coefficients of the recurrence relation
a = []
for i in range(N-2):
    a.append(random.randint(1, usedcurve.order - 1))

# then, we generate the N nonces
k = []
# the first one is random
k.append(random.randint(1, usedcurve.order - 1))
# the other ones are computed with the recurrence equation
for i in range(N-1):
    new_k = 0
    for j in range(N-2):
        new_k += a[j]*(k[i]**j) % usedcurve.order
    k.append(new_k)

# sanity check to see if we generated the parameters correctly
# print(k[1] % usedcurve.n)
# print((a[1]*k[0] + a[0]) % usedcurve.n)
# assert k[1] == ((a[1]*k[0] + a[0]) % usedcurve.n)

# then, we generate the signatures using the nonces
h = []
sgns = []
for i in range(N):
    digest_fnc = hashlib.new("sha256")
    digest_fnc.update(b"recurrence test ")
    digest_fnc.update(i.to_bytes(1, 'big'))
    h.append(digest_fnc.digest())
    # get hash values as integers and comply with ECDSA
    # strangely, it seems that the ecdsa module does not take the leftmost bits of hash if hash size is bigger than curve... perahps is because i use low level functions
    if usedcurve.order.bit_length() < 256:
        h[i] = (int.from_bytes(h[i], "big") >> (256 - usedcurve.order.bit_length())) % usedcurve.order
    else:
        h[i] = int.from_bytes(h[i], "big") % usedcurve.order
    sgns.append(privkey.sign( h[i], k[i] ))


# get signature parameters as arrays
s_inv = []
s = []
r = []
for i in range(N):
    s.append(sgns[i].s)
    r.append(sgns[i].r)
    s_inv.append(ecdsa.numbertheory.inverse_mod(s[i], usedcurve.order))


#########################################
# generating the private-key polynomial #
#########################################

# declaring stuff for manipulating polynomials with SAGE
Z = GF(usedcurve.order)
R = PolynomialRing(Z, names=('dd',))
(dd,) = R._first_ngens(1)

# the polynomial we construct will have degree 1 + Sum_(i=1)^(i=N-3)i in dd
# our task here is to compute this polynomial in a constructive way starting from the N signatures in the given list order
# the generic formula will be given in terms of differences of nonces, i.e. k_ij = k_i - k_j where i and j are the signature indexes
# each k_ij is a first-degree polynomial in dd
# this function has the goal of returning it given i and j
def k_ij_poly(i, j):
    hi = Z(h[i])
    hj = Z(h[j])
    s_invi = Z(s_inv[i])
    s_invj = Z(s_inv[j])
    ri = Z(r[i])
    rj = Z(r[j])
    poly = dd*(ri*s_invi - rj*s_invj) + hi*s_invi - hj*s_invj
    return poly

# the idea is to compute the polynomial recursively from the given degree down to 0
# the algorithm is as follows:
# for 4 signatures the second degree polynomial is:
# k_12*k_12 - k_23*k_01
# so we can compute its coefficients.
# the polynomial for N signatures has degree 1 + Sum_(i=1)^(i=N-3)i and can be derived from the one for N-1 signatures

# let's define dpoly(i, j) recursively as the dpoly of degree i starting with index j

def dpoly(n, i, j):
    if i == 0:
        return (k_ij_poly(j+1, j+2))*(k_ij_poly(j+1, j+2)) - (k_ij_poly(j+2, j+3))*(k_ij_poly(j+0, j+1))
    else:
        left = dpoly(n, i-1, j)
        for m in range(1,i+2):
            left = left*(k_ij_poly(j+m, j+i+2))
        right = dpoly(n, i-1, j+1)
        for m in range(1,i+2):
            right = right*(k_ij_poly(j, j+m))
        return (left - right)

def print_dpoly(n, i, j):
    if i == 0:
        print('(k', j+1, j+2, '*k', j+1, j+2, '-k', j+2, j+3, '*k', j+0, j+1, ')', sep='', end='')
    else:
        print('(', sep='', end='')
        print_dpoly(n, i-1, j)
        for m in range(1,i+2):
            print('*k', j+m, j+i+2, sep='', end='')
        print('-', sep='', end='')
        print_dpoly(n, i-1, j+1)
        for m in range(1,i+2):
            print('*k', j, j+m, sep='', end='')
        print(')', sep='', end='')


print("Nonces difference equation :")
print_dpoly(N-4, N-4, 0)
print(' = 0', sep='', end='')
print()
separator()

poly_target = dpoly(N-4, N-4, 0)
print("Polynomial in d :")
print(poly_target)
separator()

d_guesses = poly_target.roots()
print("Roots of the polynomial :")
print(d_guesses)
separator()

# check if the private key is among the roots
for i in d_guesses:
    if i[0] == d:
        print("key found!!!")
```

This code works flawlessly on the desktop Linux using the SageMath environment.  To make it work on my Android phone using the PyDroid 3 app, I modified the following lines:

```
from sympy import *
```

[...]

```
# declaring stuff for manipulating polynomials with SymPy
dd = symbols('dd')
Z = GF(usedcurve.order)
R = PolynomialRing(Z, symbols = ('dd',))
```

I am unable to find an adequate replacement for the SageMath function:

```
(dd,) = R._first_ngens(1)
```

In order to construct the Polynomial Ring accurately.

Also, the calculation and evaluation for finding the roots function is causing me difficulty with converting:

```
# Extracting the roots from the roots list and converting to integers within the finite field
d_guesses1 = real_roots(poly_target)
d_guesses2 = [[int(root.evalf()) % usedcurve.order] for root in d_guesses1]
```

This is the closest I've come so far to attempting to obtain the roots of the multivariate polynomial in real number/integer form.  But, am still not having any success.

I have tried using the real_roots, all_roots, solve, and roots function of SymPy without success.

Comment: Why isn't this tagged [sage]?

Comment: You say "I am unable to find an adequate replacement" and "I have tried ... without success" but it is not clear to me what it is that you expect/want or what it is that you see instead. I don't know what "without success" means or what would qualify as success or as an adequate replacement.

Comment: I haven't looked at `sage` in a long time (20+ years), and don't know how well it's been developed or followed.  Based on the tags, there's a lot more interest in  `[sympy]` now.

Comment: @hpaulj: I initially tagged SageMath but did not have sufficient reputation to do so.  I have edited this to include the sage tag.

Comment: Creating a new tag usually isn't helpful.  You want something that knowledgeable people  will be watching.  I have a bookmark with a dozen tags that I check regularly.